# Moment of Inertia of Ellipse around x axis

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

How can I calculate the moment of inertia of an ellipse ($\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$) using polar coordinates and the formula:
$$I_x=\int_\Omega y^2dx dy$$

I know that the result is supposed to be $I_x=\frac{\pi a b^3}{4}$ ($b$ corresponding to the semi-axis in the $y$ coordinate), but I just can't seem to derive it.

PS: I've read other posts on this topic but none I've found so far uses polar coordinates to get to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parametrize your ellipse by 
$$
x=ar\cos t,\ \ \ y=br\sin t,\ \ \ t\in[0,2\pi],\ \ \ r\in[0,1]. 
$$
The Jacobian is 
$$
\begin{vmatrix} a\cos t& b\sin t\\ -ar\sin t& br\cos t\end{vmatrix}=abr.
$$
So 
$$
I_x=\int_{\Omega}y^2\,dx\,dx=\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}b^2r^2\sin^2t\,abr\,dt\,dr=\pi ab^3\int_0^1r^3\,dr=\frac{\pi a b^3}4.
$$

Comment: Why is the parametrization $x=ar cos (t)$ instead of just $x=r cos(t)$?

Comment: Because you want to get the ellipse and not a circle.