# Moment of inertia of elliptical cross-sectioin in cartesian coordinates

Tags: calculus

I have seen questions previously which discuss the calculation of the moment of inertia (For example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3502009/moment-of-inertia-of-ellipse-around-x-axis)), but the solutions always are given by first transforming to polar coordinates. I would like to see the integrals in Cartesian coordinates.

Say we have

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

And so the moment of inertia about the x axis is

$$I_x=\int_\Omega y^2dx dy$$

But how would this be done without transforming to polar coordinates?  I am stuck on figuring out the limits for the integrals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$

$I_x=\int_{-a}^a\int^{b\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}_{-b\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}} \rho y^2 dydx=\rho\int_{-a}^a y^3/3| dx$

$I_x=\rho/3 \int_{-a}^a 2b^3(1-x^2/a^2)^{3/2} dx$

$u=x/a. adu=dx$

$I_x=2ab^3\rho/3 \int_{-1}^1 (1-u^2)^{3/2}du$
Assuming $a>b$.

$\sqrt{1-u^2}=\sin \theta. u=\cos \theta. du=-\sin \theta d\theta$

$\int -\sin^4\theta d\theta=\int -(1/2-(1/2)\cos 2\theta)^2 d\theta=(-1/4)\int 1 + \cos^2{2\theta}-2\cos 2\theta d\theta$

$=(-1/4)\int 1+(1/2)+(1/2)\cos {4\theta} -2\cos 2\theta d\theta=(-1/4)((3/2)\theta +(1/8)\sin{4\theta}-\sin 2\theta)+C$

$= (-3/8)\arccos (u)-(1/32)4u\sqrt{1-u^2}(2u^2-1)+(1/2)u\sqrt{1-u^2}|_{-1}^1=3\pi/8$

$I_x=\pi ab^3 \rho/4$

$\rho=M/(\pi ab)$

$I_x=\pi b^2/4$

So no polar coordinates, but trig substitution to do the integral which amounts to the same thing. I think that's why its often done that way.